# Empty Software Updater

Tags: updates, update-manager

Software Updater works as expected until no more updates are available, then it keeps showing [this empty window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgWdf.png) (I don't have enough reputation to upload an image).

When clicking in "*Install Now*", some process is done (I guess some fetching) and the same empty window appears again, quite annoying...

`sudo apt update` gives a "*All packages are up to date.*". I'm using Ubuntu 23.04 (the last time I install a non-LTS Ubuntu)